# Firebase Auth sendEmailVerification() I'm getting an Error, but only with Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, firebase-authentication

When a user signs up, I am requiring them to verify their email address.

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari, where I get the following message:

**Error: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.**

And no confirmation email is sent.

I’m sourcing this version:
firebasejs/6.4.0/firebase-auth.js

I've searched for similar problems.  There were lots of Firebase Authentication errors, but I didn't find this one.

Using the Safari JavaScript debugger, filtering for all exceptions I receive the errors below.

And interestingly, after stepping through with the debugger on, setting Breakpoints at "All Exceptions" **an email is sent.**  But not when running in real-time.

Hopefully that is a clue.

I send the email verification with this code.

```
if (current_user && !current_user.emailVerified) {

    current_user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {

        const user_message = '<message to user>';
        window.location = '/message?message=' + user_message;

    }).catch((error) => {

        console.log(error);

    } );

}
```

The errors:

line 515   rpchandler.js

```
 try {
          response = JSON.parse(this.getResponseText()) || null;
```

It looks like the response is null.

---

line 183  promise.js    Exception with thrown value: zi

```
try {
                // Promise was rejected. Step up one call frame to see why.
                if (reason instanceof Error) {
                  throw reason;
```

This happens a few times.

---

line 2190   authuser.js

```
// Cache the invalidation error.
      self.userInvalidatedError_ = /** @type {!fireauth.AuthError} */ (error);
```

---

line 740  firebase-app.js

```
Exception with thrown value: TypeError: Argument to String.prototype.startsWith cannot be a RegExp
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rolling my own email verification workflow.

I'd be interested in reverting back to the Firebase Auth JavaScript email verification workflow, if there is a solution.  But for now, I just have to move forward.